# Android app crashes after successful purchase of subscription with Google Play Billing Library

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I'm implementing Google Play's Billing Library for users to purchase in-app subscriptions. According to Google's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#solo) on testing, I can only test my code through a test release, such as an internal test release. I've gotten to this point and have attempted to purchase a test subscription using one of Google's testing product IDs. However, when normally I should see the "Purchase Successful" popup, my app crashes. I have no idea why, and have been trying to understand my problem, but since this is an internal release there aren't any logs generated (or at least none that I could find).

---

Can someone help me understand the proper method for testing Google Play's Billing Library? I don't understand how they meant for developers to test their library if we can't even view the stack trace.

Comment: You need to create subscriptions at google play console and to publish app with billing permissions to beta channel. Otherwise it won't work. Add test account. Then you'll be able to test your app. There are onFailed, on error events for almost all methods of billing library  on which you should subscribe.

Comment: I've already created subscriptions and published the app with billing permissions, but to the internal testing channel. So then the only way to properly test the billing library is to publish to beta?

Answer (score 1):

Anytime there is a crash it should appear in the logcat on your device. Are your logcat filters too aggressive? There is [some documentation on this here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat).

Comment: I ask so many stackoverflow questions and I forgot about this one. I ended up adding crashlytics to my app to view tracebacks and such in Fabric. I was able to locate the bug in my app this way. But thank you for the link, this is interesting stuff.